# Equivalent curl request in php

Tags: php, curl

Im trying to get `curl -X GET --header "Accept: application/json" --header "authorization: Bearer <API token>" "https://api.clashofclans.com/v1/clans?name=%23P8PQ8VL2"`in php

so far i came up with this

```
     $ch = curl_init(); 

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.clashofclans.com/v1/clans?name=%23P8PQ8VL2");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json'));
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  'authorization: Api key'
));

$result=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
var_dump(json_decode($result, true));
```

this is the 1st time im using curl in php, thanks in advance :)

Comment: explain what issue you getting in this code?

Comment: try it with `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json', 'authorization: Bearer <API token>'));` also remove other `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` options

Comment: im getting NULL as output...i think i have missed some quires

Answer (score 1):

Hey thank you all i got it work. i had to use

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

Comment: Glad to see it works now. So in that case it was a mix of all the code snippets and not just this. (?) Btw. not verifying the peer on a HTTPS connection is not secure. You should verify it. Leaving this on false is just for lazy programmers ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Your are overwriting the header with the second set of the options. I would build up the header array like so:

```
$headers = array();
$headers[] = "Accept: application/json";
$headers[] = "authorization: Bearer " . $yourAPItoken;
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8';
```

And send the array:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```

Comment: thanks @st2erw2od still the output is same. do you think there is something wrong with my output json code? `$result=curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
echo "$result";

var_dump(json_decode($result, true));`

Comment: Try to output some additional information about possible errors. echo `curl_errno($ch);` `echo curl_error($ch);` `var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch));` What does it say?